# How to use Magento 2 UI components in a custom module?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to use Magento 2.4 UI components on a custom module. As per the documentation, I should add a dependency for the Magento_UI module:

> To use UI components in your custom module, you need to add a dependency for the Magento_UI module in your component’s composer.json file.
>
> *https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html*

How can I do that? I've tried to add the following line in my `composer.json` but this is obviously not the right syntax:

```json
    "require": {
        "Magento_UI": "*"
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To require a Magento module in your `composer.json`, you just need to add the required line in the `"require"` section of your `composer.json`:

```json
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "magento/module-ui": "*"
    },
    ...
}
```

You can find the list of Magento modules here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/architecture/archi_perspectives/components/modules/mod_depend.html#hard-dependencies

```json
  ...
  "require": {
    "magento/module-catalog": "103.0.*",
    "magento/module-email": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-media-storage": "100.3.*",
    "magento/module-store": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-theme": "101.0.*",
    "magento/module-ui": "101.1.*",
    "magento/module-variable": "100.3.*",
    "magento/module-widget": "101.1.*",
    "magento/module-authorization": "100.3.*"
   }
   ...
```